# syntax error, unexpected token, expecting end of file

Tags: c++, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I get the following error when i run my Parser file ( binary got after compiling Flex/Bison files).
`error: syntax error, unexpected TKN_PRIMARY, expecting end of file`

Here is rule defined in flex code:

```
<PRIMARY_MME_STATE>{number} {
 lexVal = YYText();
 std::cout<<"PRIMARY MME -->  "<<lexVal<<std::endl;
 yylval->strVal = new std::string(lexVal);
 return token::TKN_PRIMARYMME;
 }
```

And my understanding is that since value of TKN_PRIMARY is zero ( which is the value defined for END  %token  END 0 "end of file") Instead of returning TKN_PRIMARY , it is expecting token END to be returned. Please comment if my understanding is correct . And Also how to tackle this issue.

Comment: I see that PRIMARY MME --> 0 getting printed and after I see nothing

Comment: you should post your input, .y and .lex file, then the problem might become obvious

Answer (score 1):

If `TKN_PRIMARY` and `END` have the same value (or, in general, if any two different tokens have the same value), then the bison parser is going to act in unpredictable ways.

Quoting the [bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Token-Decl.html#Token-Decl):

> It is generally best, however, to let Bison choose the numeric codes for
>   all token types.  Bison will automatically select codes that don't
>   conflict with each other or with normal characters.

I think that's definitely the best way of dealing with the problem.

Comment: The problem is I am not defining the value for TKN_PRIMARYMME, After scanning the log file(for which the parser have been written) token itself gets the value = 0. So what should i do now?

Comment: @user2313227: in that case, I have no idea. You haven't posted any details, and I'm not psychic :) so I don't know why you think `TKN_PRIMARY` is defined to be `0` (if you do) or what your grammar looks like.